# Mongoose Schema for hierarchical data like a folder > subfolder > file

Tags: mongoose

How do we create a Hierarchical Schema for a file system

```
var Folder = new Schema({

  'name' : String,
  'isFile' : Number,
  'children' : [Folder]
});
```

Can we do some thing like this ???

Answer (score 9):

The schema you've used embeds the children folders inside the parents. This would probably work, but it has a couple of problems.

The first is that the size of each folder document could get pretty big, depending on the size of the file system, and you might run into issues with hitting size limits.

The other issue is that it makes it very difficult to directly find documents that aren't at the top level.

A better solution is to store the parent/child relationship as references.

```
var Folder = new Schema({
    name: String,
    isFile: Boolean,
    parent: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Folder'
    },
    children: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Folder'
    }]
});
```

The ref property simply indicates in which Collection/Model mongoose should be looking for the referenced document, so it can find it if you query for it. In this case we reference a parent, which is a Folder, and a list of chilren, which are also documents of type Folder.

Storing references to the parent allow you to easily traverse up the tree, the references to the children allow you to generate the tree from the top down.

You can use the `populate` functionality of Mongoose to pull in the details from the references. See [the Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for more information on population and references.

---

N.B. I changed `isFile` to a `Boolean` field because I assume you are trying to store a yes/no value?

Comment: But where to place the "Folders" ref ?

Answer (score 6):

There are some documented approaches for storing hierarchical data on a MongoDB collection, which I cite below:

1. Child References
2. Parent References
3. An Array of Ancestors
4. Materialized Paths
5. Nested Sets

Your choice will depend most of how do you intend to query the data, each method has its own advantages and disadvantages. If you need, you can simply store hierarchical data through multiple of these methods at once, but it's important to keep them updated. For so, I do recommend a mongoose plugin.

My favorite choice is materialized paths, because it provides more flexibility in working with the path, such as finding nodes by partial paths.

I quote a example from [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/):

> The following example models the tree using Materialized Paths,
> storing the path in the field path; the path string uses the comma ,
> as a delimiter:

```
{ _id: "Books",       path: null }
{ _id: "Programming", path: ",Books," }
{ _id: "Databases",   path: ",Books,Programming," }
{ _id: "Languages",   path: ",Books,Programming," }
{ _id: "MongoDB",     path: ",Books,Programming,Databases," }
{ _id: "dbm",         path: ",Books,Programming,Databases," }
```

> 1. You can query to retrieve the whole tree, sorting by the field path:

```
Model.find().sort( { path: 1 } )
```

> 2. You can use regular expressions on the path field to find the descendants of Programming:

```
Model.find( { path: /,Programming,/ } )
```

> 3. You can also retrieve the descendants of Books where the Books is also at the topmost level of the hierarchy:

```
Model.find( { path: /^,Books,/ } )
```

> 4. You may want to retrieve the immediate children of Books:

```
Model.find( { path: /,Books,$/ } )
```

Read more on docs link above about indexing that "path" field for better performance.

Any of these approaches can be implemented by yourself or through a mongoose plugin, which you can find by searching "tree" on http://plugins.mongoosejs.com.

Comment: I find this technique the most elegant ones. Just one question, suppose i need to move a folder to another folder, how do i write query to update path of the folder being moved and all its children?

Answer (score 0):

You have use mongoose-tree or mongoose-materialized

Comment: A little elaboration on the matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So matthewtole if I understand you correctly, it would be something like this?

```
const FolderSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    isFile: Boolean,
    parent: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Folder'
    },
    files: [{
        name: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
        encodedName: { type: String, required: false, max: 100, default: null },
    }],
    owner: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    team: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Team' }
});

const Folder = mongoose.model('folders', FolderSchema);

module.exports = {
    Schema: FolderSchema,
    Folder
};
```