# query on hierarchical ref

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm searching for the best way to model this data: I have a collection of laws. Each article could have 0 paragraph (it means the paragraph is not explicitly numerated) or more (max 5).

```
var lawSchema = new Schema({
name:{type:String,required:true},
chapter:{type:String},
paragraph:[{type:Numer}]
});

var documentSchema = = new Schema({
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    article_ref:[{item:{type: ObjectId, ref: 'article'},comment:String}]
    });
```

This current schema is wrong, because a document can refers to an Article OR a specific paragraph only.
I have to be able to query the document collection in 2 ways: by law or by law paragraph.

- in the first case I want to get all the document that refers to that law X (or its paragraph).
- in the second case I want obiouvsly only the documents that refers to that law paragraph (ignoring other paragraphs)

A first and too simple solution is to "plane" this hierarchical data in "Law" collection and have a different document for each law and paragraph:

```
var lawSchema = new Schema({
name:{type:String,required:true},
});
```

the collection should look this way:

```
[
{_id:000,name:"article1"},
{_id:001,name:"article1 - paragraph 1"},
{_id:002,name:"article1 - paragraph 2"},
{_id:003,name:"article2"}
...
]
```

I don't like this because it needs an kind of big extra work in business layer to accomplish a query by article (as I said, I need the documents that refers to "article1" but also "article1 - paragraph 1")

**EDIT:** I found this question
[Mongoose Schema for hierarchical data like a folder > subfolder > file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514912/mongoose-schema-for-hierarchical-data-like-a-folder-subfolder-file)
But i'm not clear if using paths I easily retrieve a refs as I said (a ref to chapter and all its paragraph or a single paragraph)